# Building a login page

Tags: html

Does anyone have a good start for a simple front end html login? I am pretty new with html and coding in general. Also how do I connect the login with my other work such as the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Login page
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="login">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

that is just a pretty simple login form with no css to it, but I would just go to bootstrap and use their login form at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get the code from bootstrap?

Comment: right click , view page source, and copy it, make sure to include the css files.